# Finding duplicates within a file from multiple files

Tags: excel, file, unix, duplicates

I have 200 files and each file contains 600+ records.Some of the files contain duplicate records within themselves.I want to find out all the files which have duplicate records and which file has how many duplicates. Please help. I can use unix scripting or excel.

Comment: I have a unix command to find duplicates. But I have to run that command for each file. I dont want to do it in this way.

Comment: hm.. but 200 files... It will be like huge data.. Okay, I will give it a try. Please suggest if you have any other solution.

Comment: Can you tell me how to append data in a single file and putting 1st field as file number

Comment: That site is not opening in my office :-(. I am thinking of going for a loop in java.